# Enzyme mount() not rendering child components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, mount

I try to test a React component containing child components. This is not a unit test - I want to simulate a click on a subcomponent and check if the result is what I expect. My setup is (schematically) as follows:

```
<Board />
    <Row />
        <Card />
```

... where component Board contains multiple Row components and component Row contains multiple Card components (yes, it's a board game). When clicking a Card it should flip, displaying the image (yes, it's a memorygame).
So I use Enzyme's mount() on the because I want to be able to select a childcomponent of the Board.

This is the relevant rendered HTML from Chrome Developer tools Inspector tab:

[image: html output of React Board component]

Note that the Board contains Rows that contain Cards, identified by their like-named classes.

I am able to select a Card:

```
expect(component.find("[data-id='6'] .class")).toBeDefined()
```

doesn't throw error but when I simulate a click on a Card I *do* get an error.
This is my test:

```
import React from "react";
import { Board } from "../components/Board";
import { mount } from "enzyme";

let component;

beforeEach(() => {
    component = mount(<Board />);
    console.log(component.debug());
});

describe("Test the puzzle", () => {
    it("should show 1 turned card when clicked", () => {
        const button = component.find(".button");
        const card = component.find("div[data-id='7']");

        expect(button).toBeDefined();
        expect(card).toBeDefined();
        button.simulate("click");
        card.simulate("click");
    });
});
```

This gives the errors

```
● Test the puzzle › should show 1 turned card when clicked

    Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.       

      44 |              expect(card).toBeDefined();
      45 |              button.simulate("click");
    > 46 |              card.simulate("click");
         |                   ^
      47 |      });
      48 | });
      49 |
```

The debugging() output of the the Board shows a *shallow* mount: Board contains a Row but Row does not contain Cards:

```
<Board>
  <div className="container">
    <div className="board">
      <Row cards={{...}} onClick={[Function: onClickCard]} updateCardReference={[Function: updateCardReference]}>
        <div className="row" />
      </Row>
```

So that leads me to believe there's nothing wrong with my selecting DOM elements but Enzyme's mount() is doing a shallow mount instead.

What do you think?

> ```
> "react": "^16.13.1",
> "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
> "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
> "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
> "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
> ```

Comment: You're simulating a click on a button and then on a card. What is the button about? I mean, with `expect(card).toBeDefined();` you're ensuring the card is there, but after the button click it's not there anymore.

Comment: Also, if you have animations there (or other delaying mechanisms), you may need to await some millis before testing.

Comment: Since it's a memory game it works as follows:
1 user is presented with all cards with images;
2 user clicks a button 'shuffle'
3 cards with image gets style visibility:'hidden' so image is hidden and 'back' of card is displayed;
4 array with images is shuffled and applied to state so component Board re-renders.
So between button click and referencing to a card the Board component is re-rendered..

Comment: Just checked - not clicking the Button and only clicking a Card component still gives the error Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead. for card.simulate('click').

Comment: As I commented before, animations, transitions and other kind of functions with backgrounded jobs may need you to `await` a bit before proceeding. Is there anything like that or everything is rendered in the first loop? Can you `debug` the card just before its `expect`?